# Drop values of variables if they match one of other

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

```
Family   Component   x1   m_x1   x2   m_x2   x3   m_x3   y1   m_y1   y2   m_y2   y3   m_y3
a1       1           1    100    2    300    0    0      2    250    0    0      0    0
a1       2           1    100    2    300    0    0      2    250    0    0      0    01
a1       3           1    100    2    300    0    0      2    250    0    0      0    0
a2       1           2    150    0    0      0    0      0    0      0    0      0    0
a2       2           2    150    0    0      0    0      0    0      0    0      0    0
a3       1           1    4000   3    150    4    130    2    150    3    400    0    0
a3       2           1    4000   3    150    4    130    2    150    3    400    0    0
a3       3           1    4000   3    150    4    130    2    150    3    400    0    0
a3       4           1    4000   3    150    4    130    2    150    3    400    0    0
```

Family is the grouping variable. Then I want that if the value of `"Component"` (for each `Family`) do NOT match the one in `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, `y1`, `y2`, `y3`, the value of that variable and the next (for `x1`, `m_x1`, for `x2`, `m_x2`, ...) to be dropped. The result i'm looking for would be:

```
Family   Component   x1   m_x1   x2   m_x2   x3   m_x3   y1   m_y1   y2   m_y2   y3   m_y3
a1        1           1    100    0    0      0    0      0    0      0    0      0    0
a1        2           0    0      2    300    0    0      2    250    0    0      0    0
a1        3           0    0      0    0      0    0      0    0      0    0      0    0
a2        1           0    0      0    0      0    0      0    0      0    0      0    0
a2        2           2    150    0    0      0    0      0    0      0    0      0    0
a3        1           1    4000   0    0      0    0      0    0      0    0      0    0
a3        2           0    0      0    0      0    0      2    150    0    0      0    0
a3        3           0    0      3    150    0    0      0    0      3    400    0    0
a3        4           0    0      0    0      4    130    0    0      0    0      0    0
```

What function should I use? I've tried with merge but couldn't make it work.

Comment: Using `melt` on this dataframe would make this process a lot easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an easy way:

```
# find nonmatching entries
idx <- dat[-(1:2)][c(TRUE, FALSE)] != dat$Component

# full index
idx_full <- idx[ , rep(seq(ncol(idx)), each = 2)]

# replace values with 0
dat[-(1:2)][idx_full] <- 0

dat
#   Family Component x1 m_x1 x2 m_x2 x3 m_x3 y1 m_y1 y2 m_y2 y3 m_y3
# 1     a1         1  1  100  0    0  0    0  0    0  0    0  0    0
# 2     a1         2  0    0  2  300  0    0  2  250  0    0  0    0
# 3     a1         3  0    0  0    0  0    0  0    0  0    0  0    0
# 4     a2         1  0    0  0    0  0    0  0    0  0    0  0    0
# 5     a2         2  2  150  0    0  0    0  0    0  0    0  0    0
# 6     a3         1  1 4000  0    0  0    0  0    0  0    0  0    0
# 7     a3         2  0    0  0    0  0    0  2  150  0    0  0    0
# 8     a3         3  0    0  3  150  0    0  0    0  3  400  0    0
# 9     a3         4  0    0  0    0  4  130  0    0  0    0  0    0
```

where `dat` is the name of your data frame.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
cols <- as.vector(t(outer(c("x","y"), 1:3, 
                     function(...) paste(...,sep=""))))
df[, 3:ncol(df)] <- do.call(cbind, lapply(cols, function(x) df[, 
                              c(x,paste(sep="","m_",x))]*(df[[x]]==df$Component)))
```

Answer (score 1):

If the columns are always  not in the same order, you could also do:

```
 n1 <- unique(gsub(".+\\_", "", colnames(df1)[-(1:2)]))

 df1[,-(1:2)] <- do.call(cbind,lapply(n1, function(x) {
                      indx <- grep(x, names(df1))
                      m1 <- as.matrix(df1[indx])
                      m1[m1[,1]!=df1$Component] <- 0
                      as.data.frame(m1) }))
  df1
  #   Family Component x1 m_x1 x2 m_x2 x3 m_x3 y1 m_y1 y2 m_y2 y3 m_y3
  #1     a1         1  1  100  0    0  0    0  0    0  0    0  0    0
  #2     a1         2  0    0  2  300  0    0  2  250  0    0  0    0
  #3     a1         3  0    0  0    0  0    0  0    0  0    0  0    0
  #4     a2         1  0    0  0    0  0    0  0    0  0    0  0    0
  #5     a2         2  2  150  0    0  0    0  0    0  0    0  0    0
  #6     a3         1  1 4000  0    0  0    0  0    0  0    0  0    0
  #7     a3         2  0    0  0    0  0    0  2  150  0    0  0    0
  #8     a3         3  0    0  3  150  0    0  0    0  3  400  0    0
  #9     a3         4  0    0  0    0  4  130  0    0  0    0  0    0
```